# C++ strlen for the String class

Tags: c++, string

How does the C++ `length()` method work for the `std::string` class? Thanks.

Comment: What is "the String class?"  Are you referring to `std::string`?  If so, it has no `len` member function.  Are you referring to some other string class (there are dozens of others to choose from, after all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::string` class has several constructors, including one that takes both a `const char*` raw C string and a `size_t` length, and another that takes just a `const char*` raw C string. For the former, the provided length is stored, and for the latter, the length is computed once by invoking `strlen` or by performing an equivalent computation. Calling `std::string::length()const` just returns the previously computed value. It is not recomputed each time it is invoked.

Comment: The C++03 standard says `std::basic_string<>`'s `size()` (and consequently `length()`) member function "should" have constant complexity (§23.1/5). Consequently, it's technically possible for a conforming implementation to recompute `length()` each time it's called, but I very much doubt that any current standard library implementation actually does this.

Comment: @ildjarn: Doesn't "constant complexity" mean O(1)? Is it possible to *compute* the length of a string in less than O(n)?

Comment: @thkala : Yes, constant complexity means O(1), but the key word here is "should" -- the standard doesn't mandate that conforming implementations *must* have an O(1) `size()` (and `length()`), only that they *should*.

Comment: @ildjarn: ah, right. RFC-style verbs. The bane of my existence and an excellent source for debate :-)

Comment: @thkala : Well, in this case, the standard makes a clear distinction between "must" and "should" -- the `empty()` member function, for example, *must* be O(1). But, like I said, I very much doubt that any widely-used standard library implementation doesn't have an O(1) `size()`.

Answer (score 2):

Most string classes for C++ keep the length of the string in a separate member, so their `length()` method just returns that cached value.

Computing the length of a zero-terminated string in the first place is easy: start with the first element and keep incrementing a counter until you reach the binary `0` which denotes the end of the string. That's precisely what `strlen` does.

Comment: So, basically, you just run strlen once and store that number in some sort of string struct?

Comment: @Dervin Thunk : `std::string` supports embedded null characters, so nothing like `strlen` is ever run on its internal buffer, as that would return too small a number. It just keeps track of the valid data length as the string is modified.

Comment: Exactly. `std::string` knows when the length of the string is changed, so it may update its cached length as needed. For example if you construct a `std::string("abc")`, it computes the length of the string, allocates sufficient storage and stores a copy along with the length.

Comment: @ildjarn: Too small or WAY too high. :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : Good point. I was thinking specifically of the case where the `string`'s data contained embedded nulls, but you're right -- `std::string` isn't guaranteed to null-terminate its buffer, so running `strlen` on the buffer could be pathological.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work on most implementations. It merely *cheats* by returning a value that other methods strived *hard* to maintain:

From libstdc++ `string.h`:

```
///  Returns the number of characters in the string, not including any
///  null-termination.
size_type
length() const
{ return _M_rep()->_M_length; }
```

Same thing happens in Java, by the way. Apparently `length()` methods are habitual cheaters...

Comment: What do you mean by "cheater"?  What rule(s) get broken?

Comment: @Michael J: The OP asked an arguably broad and ambiguous question on how the `length()` method *"works"*. I felt the need to answer somewhat tongue-in-cheek that it doesn't really *do* anything - it merely returns an existing value. The dig was towards the question, not towards `length()` :-)

Comment: It appears that the questioner is a novice and your comment is likely to do little else than to confuse him.  It is better to help novices than to make fun of them.  We were all beginners at one time in our lives.  :-)

Comment: @Michael: the OP may be a novice in C++, but they have over 2k reputation on StackOverflow. They should know by now that questions need more attention than this. The original question, before being edited, was barely understandable. This one, by not mentioning specific things that the OP needs help to understand, shows a lack of research before posting the question...

Comment: OK, if you feel the need to belittle people, so be it.  I have better things to do than argue with you.